# POST a File Using vb.net based on CURL command

Tags: vb.net, curl, webrequest

I will start this off by setting the stage. I am new to vb.net and programming in general. We are in the process of converting our front end Access program to vb.net. During this process someone started using FormStack, WebMerge and CudaSign while our program is being converted. Our program handles the FormStack and WebMerge stuff, what we want now is to be able to send these documents to CudaSign for clients to be able to sign.
Through days of research I have been able to successfully create a user and retrieve a token needed for uploading the file.
The instruction I have are of little help to me because I know nothing about any of this.

The cURL statement is:
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' -F 'file=@FILE_NAME' https://capi-eval.signnow.com/api/document

What I have so far:

```
 Public Shared Function postFile(ByVal url As String, toSerialize As String, strHeader As String) As DataTable
    Dim strmFile As New FileStream(toSerialize, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
    Dim wHeader As WebHeaderCollection = New WebHeaderCollection
    wHeader.Clear()
    wHeader.Add(strHeader)
    Dim wReq As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
    'Dim postData As String = toSerialize
    wReq.Headers = wHeader
    wReq.Method = "POST"
    wReq.ContentType = "multipart/form-data"
    wReq.ContentLength = strmFile.Length

    Dim dataStream As Stream = wReq.GetRequestStream()
    Dim inData As Byte() = New Byte(strmFile.Length - 1) {}
    Dim bytesRead As Integer = strmFile.Read(inData, 0, strmFile.Length)
    dataStream.Write(inData, 0, strmFile.Length)

    strmFile.Close()
    Dim wResp As WebResponse = wReq.GetResponse()
    MsgBox(CType(wResp, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
    dataStream = wResp.GetResponseStream()
    Using reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim respFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        Dim dtCudaFile As DataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)("[" & respFromServer & "]")
        MsgBox(dtCudaFile.Rows(0).ToString)
        iqSTAMP.gvCudaClients.DataSource = dtCudaFile
        reader.Close()
        dataStream.Close()
        wResp.Close()
        Return dtCudaFile
    End Using
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

My Question is what is the -F='file=@FILE_NAME' expecting? A string doesn't seem to work. Maybe more specifically what is the @? Also, is there a better way to do this?

Further more here is the cURL statement for creating a client:
curl -H 'Authorization: Basic ENCODED_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS' --data '{"first_name":"Test", "last_name":"User","email":"user@test.com", "password":"test"}' https://capi-eval.signnow.com/api/user

and my code that successfully runs this:

```
    Public Shared Function postRequest(ByVal url As String, ByVal toSerialize As Object, strHeader As String) As DataTable
    Dim wHeader As WebHeaderCollection = New WebHeaderCollection
    wHeader.Clear()
    wHeader.Add(strHeader)
    Dim wReq As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
    Dim postData As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toSerialize)
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
    wReq.Headers = wHeader
    wReq.Method = "POST"
    wReq.ContentType = "application/json"
    wReq.ContentLength = byteArray.Length

    Dim dataStream As Stream = wReq.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()

    Dim wResp As WebResponse = wReq.GetResponse()

    MsgBox(CType(wResp, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
    dataStream = wResp.GetResponseStream()
    Using reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim respFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        Dim dtCudaClient As DataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)("[" & respFromServer & "]")
        MsgBox(dtCudaClient.Rows(0).ToString)
        iqSTAMP.gvCudaClients.DataSource = dtCudaClient
        reader.Close()
        dataStream.Close()
        wResp.Close()
        Return dtCudaClient
    End Using
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

UPDATE: I figured out Fiddler and went through CudaSigns website to upload a file. This is how it is formatted:

```
POST https://signnow.com/proxy/index.php/document HTTP/1.1
Host: signnow.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 130269
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: https://signnow.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryKL4kOmxYJU4yAmfq
Referer: https://signnow.com/app/account?upload=1429548553882
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: SNTooltipPresentation-Session-DockFirstTime=true; __distillery=v20150227_62e2ac9d-afa9-4bf4-bcb9-f274dd69dde1; email=pcasey%40infoqwest.net; SNTooltipPresentation-Session-SignatureWindow=true; signnowpurchasecookie=twelve_dollars_per_user; _ga=GA1.2.1823410227.1427173595; AWSELB=71BF89DD1C8E4B50D0322FBC8BE6CADD106081F9D15080EB8ED1032966C88138EDD4A5CB885B172D889C54E0A93AE079C744AE6A31914D5F430F7EF5D17B7728585B6641D1; visitor_id10742=354511558; __utma=187131127.1823410227.1427173595.1429500610.1429548417.4; __utmb=187131127.11.9.1429548510020; __utmc=187131127; __utmz=187131127.1429500610.3.3.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); session=m05vam1n9uh1pcaptnk7c9lfl3; isActiveMember=true; SNTooltipPresentation-Session-addFields=true

------WebKitFormBoundaryKL4kOmxYJU4yAmfq
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="CudaSignTest.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
(then there is the encoded file stream)
```

This looks closer to some of the posts I've seen pertaining to uploading a file via vb.net webrequest, but I still am lost as to what is going on and how their example translates to this. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

WebMerge actually has an integration (called a delivery) with CudaSign that you can use to automatically send the documents for signature without having to do any programming.  Have you tried using that integration?

Comment: We are trying to get away from Formstack and Webmerge. Someone in IT set those up without approval. We need way more control over what we are doing than either of those provide. IT thought it would be a good temporary solution, but like I said it just doesn't have the capabilities we are looking for.
Thank you though.